# Callbacks within Streams on('data') and on('end') and Mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, callback, stream, mongoose

I am reading a large `.csv` file using `fast-csv`

**myFile.js**

```
var count = 0;
var stream = fs.createReadStream("name of file");
fcsv(stream)
  .on('data', function(data) {
    ModelName.find(query, function(err, docs) {
      console.log('docs', docs);
      count = count++;
    });
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('done', count);
  })
  .parse();
```

The script runs and a list of `docs` is printed out and the `on('end')` is triggered.

How do I get the `count` value to print out the number of `docs`?  Currently it prints out `0`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up two different incremental styles with your `count` variable. Lets look at this little example to highlight it:

```
var counter = 0
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    counter = counter++ //<-- the bug is right here
};
console.log(counter) // prints 0
```

What happens is that `counter++` on the right side is post-incremental. That means `counter++` evaluates to the original value of `counter` (meaning 0) and increments `counter` by 1. After that the original value is assigned to the left-side `counter`.

What you want to write instead is any of these:

- `counter = ++counter`
- `counter = counter + 1`
- `counter++`
- `counter += 1`